# Why are these two divs being pushed over so slightly to down?

Tags: css, html

My HTML is simple, I have a content area that wraps around everything and inside it I want three columsn. Two of them have to have fixed widths, and main content area should be flexible.

I wonder what I'm doing wrong - EDIT here is the complete code sorry if it's a bit long!:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
    <link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>    
    <div id="header">
        <img src="../../Content/images/cumaviLogo.png" alt="Cumavi.com - Compras y ventas online en Bolivia!" />    
        <ul id="topuserbar">
            <li>Bienvenidos, <span class="userSalute">Sergio!</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mis Anuncios</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Perfil</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ayuda</a><img class="helpicon" src="../../Content/images/helpIcon.png" alt="Help icon." width="20" height="20"/></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cerrar Sesion</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="headershadow">
    </div>
    <div id="body">
        <div id="leftnavigation"></div>
        <div id="contentarea"></div>
        <div id="advertisingarea">
        </div>
    </div>


    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
</body>
</html>


body
{
    background-image: url('images/test.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#header
{
    background-image: url('images/headerBackground.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    width:auto;
}

#headershadow
{
    background-color:Black;
    min-height:2px;
}

#topuserbar
{
    font-family:Georgia;
    font-size:large;    
    float:right;
    margin-top:35px;  
    margin-right:15px;
}

#topuserbar ul
{
}

#topuserbar li
{
    display:inline;
    margin-left:10px;
    color:#fff;
}

#topuserbar .helpicon
{
    position:relative;
    top:4px;
    left:2px;
}

#topuserbar a
{
    color:White;
}

#topuserbar a:hover
{
    color:Yellow;
}

/*****************BODY AREA*******************/

#body
{
    border: 1px solid red;
    min-height:800px;
    width:960px;
}

#leftnavigation
{
    border: 1px solid green;
    min-height:500px;
    float:left;
    width:190px;
}

#contentarea
{
    border:1px solid blue;
    min-height:500px;
    float:left;
    width:590px;
}

#advertisingarea
{
    border:1px solid orange;
    width:150px;
    float:left;
    min-height:500px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: what browser are you using. seems to work fine in jsfiddle.

Comment: I dont see the error in chrome...

Comment: @Sergio Could you give as the complete code? the one matching the picture, maybe there is a problem there! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because of the cumulative 1 pixel border?

Answer (score 0):

Sergio, I'm not sure if this is going to be the answer but try replacing borders with outlines. Borders have a pixel width whereas outlines don't. This may, possibly, solve your problem.

CSS usage: `outline{1px solid red;}`

Comment: Thanks for the outline, tip; I'll use that from now on. But I'm still seeing the divs move down a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be:

```
#headershadow
{
    background-color:Black;
    min-height:2px;
```

Answer (score 0):

The height and padding above/below the `<ul id=topuserbar>` is pushing down the second and third divs.
Add `height:43px;` (or greater) to #header to push elements below it down and that will line up the 3 body divs.

Firebug is your friend!